# How to split dataset into multiple subsets and export them to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to export my final result table as an Excel file in SQL Server but it's not really working because the size of my data is way too big. I have 5,000,000 + observations in my current dataset and is there way I can split them into by five different subsets?

```
For example, 
subset1 = first 1,000,000 observations
subset2 = next  1,000,000 observations
subset2 = next  1,000,000 observations
subset2 = next  1,000,000 observations
subset2 = last  1,000,000 observations
```

I thought something like this would work but I couldn't figure out how to get the next 1,000,000 data into the second subset and so on.

```
Select TOP 1000000 *
into Subset1
From Table
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate the subsets with an offset, e.g.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY some_col) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

INSERT INTO Subset2 (col1, col2, ..., colN)
SELECT col1, col2, ..., colN
FROM cte
WHERE rn > 1000000 AND rn <= 2000000;    -- e.g. for second subset, etc.
```

Note the concept of "first" or "second" subset only is well defined if there exist one of more columns which defines that ordering.  In the snippet above, I assume there is a single column `some_col` which you want to use for this purpose.  You may replace it with something else as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

@Tim Biegeleisen actually give a great solution and I'm here to provide another choice using `ntile()`.

If you sure you want to split data into 5 set regrdless how many rows. use

```
select ntile(5) over(order by col) as setnumber
```

this will evenly distribute your rows in to 5 groups.
check for more info at [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)